# Оптимизация метода

Tags: java

Недавно на собеседовании попалась задачка, где нужно было переписать метод так, чтобы он работал быстро и на больших входных данных.

```
public int solution (int[] A){
    N = A.length;
    result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            if (A[i] != A[j])
                result = Math.max(result, j - i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Буду благодарен, если подтолкнете в нужном направлении как это решать.

Answer (score 4):

Если посмотреть на код, то результат - максимальное расстояние между 2 неодинаковыми элементами.

Не трудно заметить, что один из этих 2 элементов будет крайний слева или крайний справа. Дальше просто реализация за O(N) в худшем случае.

Comment: Меня программная реализация и волнует. Покажите, пожалуйста, как  можно перестроить метод?

Comment: @exStas вы не смогли реализовать то что я написал? Вы точно поняли мой ответ?

Comment: Чисто для себя - в конечном итоге это означает. зафиксировать один из концов и одним проходом по массиву, с противоположной стороны. проверять значения сравнивая с данным элементом ?

Comment: @xAqweRx да, так. Только странное задание - `solution` фактически считает длину массива, то есть расстояние между 1-м и последним элементом. Тогда можно вообще убрать двойной цикл и оставить `result = A.Length - 1` :)

Comment: Это только в том случае. если они все разные. Но в случае, если значения одинаковы - тут начинается уже вопрос.

Comment: @xAqweRx да, фиксируем крайний и идём с другого конца, пока не найдём 1 не мовпадающий. Потом в обратную сторону.

Answer (score 0):

Если кто-то не разобрался, то вот готовое решения (как получилось у меня):

```
public static int solution(int data[])
{
    int result = 0;

    int count = data.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (data[i - 1] != data[i] || data[i - 1] != data[count - i])
        {
            result = Math.max(result, count - i);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

UPD: Все же есть проблема, не доглядел все моменты.